HowTo enable "monitor on Audio device" (=virtual microphone) in 24.04 with pipewire
With pulse audio (pulse audio control) you could enable a "monitor" on an audio device, which then acts as a virtual microphone that records what is played on speaker.
How to best do this with the current ((k)ubuntu 24.04) pipewire system? If not possible via configuration, do I have to replace the entire sound system or just a part (or is there some package?
(I didn't want to replace the whole sound system just because I couldn't find the right configuration (google is (un)helpfully offering to "configure monitor sound" - that is to configure speakers integrated into displays...), and a to install pulseaudio parallel to pipewire seems like a bad idea.)
